# "socket closed by remote peer" ios for large files in XMPP framework

Tags: ios, error-handling, xmppframework, gcdasyncsocket

I am using the XMPP Framework for chat application where I am transferring files [Small(2-5 mb), Medium(20-40 mb), Large(80-100 mb)]. Now, the problem is that when I am trying to send medium sized file i keep on receiving the following errors. Could anybody let me know what could be the cause or how to resolve this issue?

```
1. FILE TRANSFER FAILED: Error Domain=XMPPOutgoingFileTransferErrorDomain Code=501 "<feature-not-implemented xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>" UserInfo=0x175e69d40 {NSLocalizedDescription=<feature-not-
 implemented xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/
2. FILE TRANSFER FAILED: Error Domain=Time Out Code=404 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Time Out error 404.)
3. FILE TRANSFER FAILED: Error Domain=GCDAsyncSocketErrorDomain Code=7 "Socket closed by remote peer" UserInfo=0x1762720c0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Socket closed by remote peer.
```

Comment: Default file size limit for server is 5Mb. If you want to send big data you need to contact server admin for increasing file limit.

Answer (score 0):

Generally when the server is closing the connection, you get this error/ Two reasons when the server closes the connection:

1. You are not sending regular pings if the client idle.
2. You are logging in from some different client with the same credentials.